# Can't connect Oracle 11g2 Database to Job Scheduler Agent on client/application server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, jobs

Running 11g2 database on one Linux server and installed Oracle client and job scheduler agent on separate Linux (application) server sitting next to it. The connection betweeen them worked fine for years.

Then I changed the host names for the both the db and app servers.

Database Server Host Name Change:

```
host4.old_domainname.com --> host4.new_domainname.com
```

Application Server Host Name Change:

```
host3.old_domainname.com --> host3.new_domainname.com
```

I didn't change the IP addresses, nor the Oracle database SID or service name. I updated the schagent.cont file HOST_NAME appropriately, as well as `/etc/hosts` files on both servers. The `tnsname.ora` and `listener.ora` files assigned 'HOST=host4' so I didn't update them. Then I rebooted the servers and brought up the DB, listener and schagent, but get an error:

```
Thu Dec 31 21:54:00 2020
Errors in file /home/dbname/oracle/diag/rdbms/dbname/dbname/trace/dbname_j000_11467.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "schemaname"."jobname"
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 4966
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 6898
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 3975
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Looking for hints how to troubleshoot/fix.

Comment: Oracle has a script you need to run when a host name changes.

Comment: Thanks - can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: Yep, it starts with ch or chg.

Comment: Is there instructions somewhere from Oracle or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, Oracle has good documentation on this. You should have read it first.

Comment: Btw 'HOST=host4', I've never known Oracle not to use FQDN. Also inside the database. Did you check initXXXX.ora?

Comment: It worked for years using simply 'host4'. (see for example, http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oracle_change_hostname.htm). I checked initXXXX.ora and it shows 'db_domain=old_domainname.com'. Note that the 'service_name' in tnsnames.ora is 'host4.old_domain.com', so they're consistent. 'service_name' is not present in initXXXX.ora file. After the domain name changed on host4 (database server) and host3 (app server), the job scheduler agent on host3 besides updating schagent.conf to 'host3.new_domain.com', what else needs to be done?

Comment: If we had instead changed only the database server hostname, not the app server hostname, would anything need to change on the app server's job scheduler agent side? This is just for my understanding.

Comment: When Oracle tries to resolve host4.old_domain.com, what happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117928/discussion-between-gerard-h-pille-and-user46688).